# Does iPhone "manual backup" in iTunes use encryption?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

Hey I have set "Automatically Back Up" to "This computer" including encryption once and because of battery life issues, I want to perform a backup and restore. Under "Manually Back Up and Restore" I clicked "Back Up Now" but it didn't ask me for a password.

However, I want to keep my health data. Is the manual backup going to include health data now or do only automatic backups include those?

[image]

Comment: If you save an Encrypted Backup to your computer, it will save all data off of your phone, including system files. To create an encrypted backup, you must click "This Computer". It does not require a password to backup, but does upon restore. If you have forgotten the password used, you may delete the previous backup from the menu bar in `iTunes -> Preferences -> Backups`.

Comment: @bret I'm not sure what relevance your comment has to this question? Can you clarify how this helps with the problem OP is having? OP is aware what an encrypted backup is. Clicking This Computer is not necessary to create an encrypted backup — this is false. Occasionally, iTunes *does* ask for a password to create the backup, since it needs to know what password you would like to use for the encryption. The question is not asking about forgotten passwords?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since the check box is selected, the local backup is encrypted and includes your Health data. The backup will use the same password you provided for the last backup, so won't ask you again this backup.

This is a very poor UI: even though you're not performing an automatic backup, the box is still used when performing a manual backup. You can verify the contents of a backup using an app such as [iBackupBot](http://www.icopybot.com/itunes-backup-manager.htm).

Comment: I was afraid of clicking "Restore" in the prompt after "Restore Backup" because I thought it might start the process without asking me for a password (which then means no Health data). Trusting your answer, I tried and it did ask me for the pw in another prompt after that so I am confident that the health data is in there now. Thanks a lot mate. And yes you are right, this is an awful UI choice - looks good but is confusing af

Comment: @user2875404 If this answered your question, you can mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: Wanted to do that just before going to bed and it told me "wait x minutes" so I hoped you'd remind me today haha sure thing mate